# How to mock a class in Python so it could be cast to list?

Tags: python, list, unit-testing, casting, mocking

I encountered a case where the method I wrote the unit test for had some class instantiations in it. The instantiated class had file open calls in its `__init__` I didn't want to patch one by one, so I decided to patch the whole class. But later in the method the class was cast to a list.

Example:

```
class ClassUnderTest:

   def hard_to_test_method(self):
       something_to_do()
       a = ClassWithSideEffects()
       b = ClassWithSideEffects()
       something_else_to_do()
       return list(b)
```

I didn't find proper documentation how to solve such a case.

Answer (score 1):

After long google searching I found hints for the solution here: https://programmaticallyspeaking.com/mocking-__iter__-with-a-magic-mock-in-python.html

The solution is short fortunately:

```
    @patch("class_with_side_effects.ClassWithSideEffects", return_value=MagicMock())
    def test_hard_to_test_method(self, mock_class):
        mock_class.return_value.__iter__.return_value = [1, 2, 3]
        c = ClassUnderTest()
        assert c.hard_to_test_method() == [1, 2, 3]
```

Explanation:

- The return_value of a patched (mocked) class will be the result when you instantiate the mocked class. Therefore object `c` is a `MagicMock` instance.
- In the first line of the definition (`mock_class.return_value.__iter__.return_value = [1, 2, 3]`) we set the `__iter__` magic method's return value. This magic method responds when `len()` is called on the object.
- The trick is the `@patch` line. By default a patch returns a `Mock` instance, but this time we need a `MagicMock` instance instead as only `MagicMock` will respond to the `len()` call as we expect as it has more suitable `__iter__` handling for this case than the plain `Mock` class.

Comment: Note that there's no need to use `MagicMock` here. Using the regular `Mock` by removing `return_value=MagicMock()` will work just as well. `len` is not used when converting an iterable to a list.

Comment: For me switching to MagicMock from Mock made it work (I used Python 3.6). When converting to list, `self.__next__()` method is called. In case of mock, it started to return the given return_values then it returned `self` in every iteration forever, `StopIteration` was never raised.